# Mercurial Merging only certain changesets

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Ok, so we recently converted from SVN to Mercurial.
We are using TortoiseHG normally.
In our one repository we have all of our projects, C++ / .NET / ASP. We have about 100 projects, all using common library projects.

So it would be quite difficult task to create multiple repo's for each project. 

Now, we have the `default` branch, and let's say `branchA`. 
I'm working on `BranchA` and adding my uber changes to it, and I change a common library, let's say an extension method

I want to commit this to `branchA` and `default`, how would I go about this?

However, I don't want all my changes from `branchA` to be merged into `default`, and I don't want all the other changes from `default`

Hopefully this is sufficient information!

Comment: This is the wrong way to use version control to manage your projects.  If you have a library shared between several projects the library should have its own repository.  Manually dealing with changes like this is going to cause you endless problems in the long run.

Comment: @PeterGraham mega-repos are used at very large companies like [Facebook](https://code.facebook.com/posts/218678814984400/scaling-mercurial-at-facebook/) with good success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to avoid this problem. You can [make all your changes on separate feature branches from some baseline revision](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/11/linus-on-branching.html), typically the tag of the last release or some other stable point `S`.

That way, your change `X` will be on its own branch which can be merged with other branches (merges `M1` and `M2`) without introducing unwanted changesets:

```
-----S--o----o---M1----o---> default
     |          /
     |---------X   feature or bugfix
     |          \
     \--o---o----M2----o-----> BranchA
```

This only requires normal `hg merge` operations; no need for patches, [Transplant](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension) or [MQ](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension).

Answer (score 23):

Just to keep things a bit updated: there is the [graft command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft) which implements cherry-picking in Mercurial.

> This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to copy individual changes
>   from other branches without merging branches in the history graph.
>   This is sometimes known as 'backporting' or 'cherry-picking'. By
>   default, graft will copy user, date, and description from the source
>   changesets.

Answer (score 5):

If you separate the common code into its own repository, you can use subrepos to include it in each project.

By the way, I *would* recommend to have a separate repository for each project, especially if there are so many.

Answer (score 3):

What is want is not merge, but cherry-pick. You can use  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension, but be aware about complications mentioned there.

Answer (score -1):

You're describing "cherry picking" or doing a "partial merge" which isn't possible with Mercurial currently. You have a few options:

- Separate your common code into its own repository.
- Generate a diff of your changes that you made to your common code, and apply that to the `default` branch.

Comment: Downvoted because mercurial does support cherry picking.  Mercurial calls it 'transplant', and it's available using the Transplant Extension.